# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type uilabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I receive this error above for this code down here. Could someone help explain to me, what this means? thanks in advance.

```
[self setSpeedView:speedCount];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a label to a string, when you want to set the label's *text*. Use this code instead:

```
self.speedView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", speedCount];
```